# Test LDAP connection using LDAP search

Tags: linux, ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

Our Spring application deployed on Linux is failing with Acces Denied to issue a token. As the same code and setup works on other VM's I am speculating there could be an issue connecting to the LDAP server.

These are the settings in spring-security-config.xml-

```
<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldaps://ldap.sample.com:740"
manager-dn="cn=sample-QA,ou=applicationusers,o=company"
manager-password="fakepassword" />
```

How do I use LDAPsearch to test the LDAP connection? Are there any existing test applications that I could use?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hard to say, I don't do `spring`, at a guess I'd say:  `ldapsearch -H "ldaps://ldap.samplecom:740" -D "cn=sample-QA,ou=applicationusers,o=company" -W ` should at least give you feedback on whether it reaches the server (`-W` should prompt for a password).  But I don't have access to an ldapserver these days to confirm, hence a comment, not an answer ...

Comment: As you are using `LDAPS` make sure that TLS server authentication works as expected, i.g. the server sends the whole certificate chain and the JVM trusts the issuer of the certificate. Furthermore make sure that the server certificate has the correct `CN` set in the subject DN (or has set correct SubjectAlternativeName extension).
From the apps host, check TCP / TLS connection by using `openssl s_client -connect ldap.sample.com:740` it will also show you the certificate chain.